# What is it called when the conclusion of one syllogism is inserted as the minor premise of a second?

Tags: logic, syllogism

As an example in Lewis's "Mere Christianity," he argues for objective morality with:

- Major: If you can judge one moral code (M1) to be better than another (M2) then objective morality exists.
- Minor: M1 is better than M2.
- Conclusion: Objective morality exists.

He then takes the conclusion of objective morality existing in this syllogism to prove God is real.

- Major: If objective morality exists, then God is real.
- Minor: Objective morality exists.
- Conclusion: God is real.

These are also both modus ponens. Are there different names for it if you are inserting arguments from different structures?

Comment: What you described is usually associated with SORITES. Thes are polysyllogisms with more than one conclusion. That is fancy talk for saying you have more than one argument that is related in such a way to premises yield a conclusion & then that conclusion necessitates another conclusion. That is you have more than just two premises as basic syllogisms are defined as. One thing to note all syllogisms have two premises whether they are listed or not.  ENTHYMES are another type of related  syllogism.  these can both exist at the same time. Because you see only one premise doesn't mean there is 1.